# windows store application in c# using client server technique

Tags: c#, windows, client, store, server

i want to develop a simple client server app for sharing data in the same network .i don't know how to do that in windows store app.can i use loop back I.P if i want to check the functionality on the same host.please give me  some useful links to get head start thanks.

Comment: you need to write a server software and a client app.
There are multiple ways of communication you could look into REST, other RPC frameworks or Socket if you want to get more down to hardware. An app is like a regular piece of software in terms of server communication. you can use 128.0.0.1 a.k.a the loopback or localhost a.k.a loopback alias. A quick sidenote, REST/RPC is usually used to send small commands i think Socket whould fit nicely for filesharing

Comment: i want to use socket programming technique in order to established a connection b/w client and server . any tutorial link that would be helpful would be great

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a server software and a client app. We already talked alittle in the comments, and you have decided on Socket so here is some nice starter information.

A nice place to learn about the basics of socket communication is the MSDN pages, here you have some basic examples for synchronous and async (you shold play around with these.

[MSDN - Socket Code Examples](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w89fhyex(v=vs.110).aspx)

I would recommend you to use async server so that the calls coming in can come from multiple sources and handled in a more "parallel" way.

[MSDN - Asynchronous Server Socket Example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te(v=vs.110).aspx)

For the client if you want to send files at the same time you should use async here as well, if you only want one and one transfer then synchronously whould be a little bit simpler maybe.
[MSDN - Asynchronous Client Socket Example (Your APP)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bew39x2a(v=vs.110).aspx)